CRM Analytics Dataset containerId/versionId based on Dataset API Name
Introduction
I have the following code in LWC:
    @wire(getDataset, { datasetIdOrApiName: 'AppUsageAnalyticsDataCombined' })
    onGetDataset({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.datasetId = data.id;
            this.datasetVersionId = data.currentVersionId;
        } else if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    @wire(executeQuery, { query: '$saqlQuery' })
    onExecuteQuery({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.records = data.results.records;
        } else if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

which works as expected.
Issue
However, I would like to move record retrieval to Apex.
Here is my code:
String query = 'q = load "MyDatasetApiName";';
query += ' ... ';
            
ConnectApi.LiteralJson result = ConnectApi.Wave.executeQuery(query);

I am getting the following error: wave.WaveQueryException: Invalid empty containerId/versionId in 'MyDatasetApiName'
As I found in the load documentation:

If you’re working in the Analytics REST API, dataset must be the containerId/versionId.

My code should look like this:
String query = 'q = load "containerId/datasetVersionId";';
query += ' ... ';
            
ConnectApi.LiteralJson result = ConnectApi.Wave.executeQuery(query);

Question
I want to avoid IDs hardcoding.
Is there a simple way to get containerId and datasetVersionId dynamically based on Dataset API Name in Apex?
I need something similar to the getDataset method in LWC.
All examples I've found have hardcoded IDs or required API callouts to GET /wave/datasets/${datasetIdOrApiName}.
